# Google Sheets: Using Transpose on an array in other tabs & identifying the tab by

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, vlookup, transpose

I would appreciate some help, please.
I have a google sheet with many tabs with data going horizontally.
I would like to create a formula that imports and transposes the data into a vertical list.
However, I want to be able to type in (or drop-down list) to select the tab which the transpose formula to look at. I cannot get anything to work. I have tried this

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1&!B2:J2)
```

To add to that if it could use a lookup (vlookup or hlookup) to find the correct row to transpose then that would be great also.
I have set up a test sheet below. Please help. Many Thanks Tim https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Menn6Z1mLl8wYOrcdQFnfs7Lp0dbC9UJe1S3AQRcOS0/edit#gid=0

Comment: I have made some progress using this formula

Comment: I have made some progress using this formula =TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(importrange(B1,A1&"!b16:j16")))
However, I manually entered the range string, the next step is to find a way of looking up the range_string in the tab specified in A1. I am failing at this step.
=TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(importrange(B1,VLOOKUP(C1,importrange(B1,A1&"!A1:Z88"),1,1))))
This results in an error - "Cannot find range or sheet for imported range"
please help
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Menn6Z1mLl8wYOrcdQFnfs7Lp0dbC9UJe1S3AQRcOS0/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

You should not use IMPORTRANGE to work with data that exists anywhere in the same spreadsheet. IMPORTRANGE is for use retrieving data from a separate spreadsheet.

Instead, delete your current Sheet1!A2 formula and replace it with this:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(A1&"!B16:J16")))`

I also added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with an advanced formula that accomplishes your lookup using whatever is types in B1. If whatever is typed in B1 exists in Column A of the selected sheet, the results of that row will be retrieved. If no match is found, `IFERROR` will return "No Match Found."

That formula, in 'Erik Help'!A2:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(A1&"!B"&VLOOKUP("*"&B1&"*",{INDIRECT(A1&"!A:A"),ROW(INDIRECT(A1&"!A:A"))},2,FALSE)&":"&VLOOKUP("*"&B1&"*",{INDIRECT(A1&"!A:A"),ROW(INDIRECT(A1&"!A:A"))},2,FALSE))),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"),"No Match Found"))`